# MSAccess use of special character

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have got a very strange problem.
In the earlier version of programm i have found the following statement inside a query.

```
table1!field1 > table2!Field2
```

I ma not able to understand the meaning of the `!` sign here.
Can any one able to help me in this regard
thank you in advance

Comment: ! could be . table1.field1 > table2.Field2  Comparing field1 is greater than field2

Comment: Post the full SQL. It's not correct syntax within the SQL, but it can be fine if you're working with a recordset in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**!** means default property with String parameter type in VB/VBA. Apparently **Table** object has default property **Field("fieldname")** and **Field** object has default property **Value**, thereby instead of **table1.Field("field1").Value** you can use shortcut notation **table1!field1**.